# How to add extension to terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I would like to create an 'extension' for the gnome terminal which will call a certain script when the terminal is closed. Where can I find information on how to accomplish this?

Specifically, I want to copy all the text in the terminal and save it as a text file somewhere as a record for later. I have this fear of losing my terminal history at the moment, but I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `screen` (you may have to `sudo apt install screen` first).

Read `man screen, or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/screen.1.html

Using `screen`'s magic keystroke <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd>, once the process you're running exits,

```
C-a h       (hardcopy)    Write a hardcopy of the current window to the file "hardcopy.n".
```